# Catalog Sync Failed for Category in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am running composite Cron Job where data will flow to multiple site catalogs. that is from global staged to global online and from online to various staged version site catalogs.
global staged to global online data sync completed for different languages where as from global online to
site specific catalog data is missing for few languages which is due to below error.

ERROR [CompositeCronjob::de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.jalo.ServicelayerJob] (00010Z0P) [CatalogVersionSyncMaster] sync ended with 4 unfinished items - see last sync media for details
ERROR [CompositeCronjob::de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.jalo.ServicelayerJob] (00010Z0P) [CatalogVersionSyncJob] Finished synchronization in 0d 00h:05m:47s:002ms. There were errors during the synchronization!

Note:
There are no logs in HMC

Answer (score 0):

You need to check console log for details. Also you can see same log in cronjob logs. Catalog synchronization not failed, only some items failed. It can be related with missing properties such as name, description, translations, related items, etc for these items.